# How do I populate the reference object in EF if I populate the model using a stored proc?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following model:

```
public partial class Names
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int LastNameRef { get; set; }

    public virtual LastNameModel LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a stored proc in SQL that does the following:

```
select id, FirstName, LastNameRef from Names
```

Now, I am calling the stored proc in C# by doing the following:

```
var ret = this.Database.SqlQuery<Names>("dbo.RetrieveFirstNames").ToList();
```

The issue with the above is that the LastNameModel object is never properly populated and comes back as null. Is there a way to do this using EF automatically?

What I've done instead is manually update it afterwards by going through the collection and finding the proper `LastNameModel` object that has the reference key of 'LastNameRef'.

Comment: You could look at having your stored proc return multiple result sets. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

As you have added the `virtual` keyword to `LastName` then this property will be lazy loaded - i.e. not populated until referenced in your code, thus invoking another RPC call to the database to get the relevant data.

Your model will need to replicate what your stored procedure will return and thus needs to be a flat structure. If you want the `LastNameModel` details then you will have to include its columns in your model and stored procedure `SELECT`.

Comment: Sorry. I had to change model names and forgot it when i pasted it here. But all the names would have been correct.

Comment: I've removed the relevant section of the answer. However, the rest of my comments hold true: if you want to populate the model as is you will have to let EF generate the SQL query by using LINQ to Entities. i.e. `dbContext.Names.Include(n => n.LastName).ToList()`. With a stored procedure EF can't map a column being returned to a particular table and thus populate the model you currently have.